# Print 'key' if given 'value' matches in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check if the 'value' exists in python dictionary and if matches print the 'key'. The problem is, values are in the list.

This script will give the server name based on the provided domain name. It will query the predefined nameserver and gives output accordingly.

I have tried following but it keeps giving me the same output.

```
 if [k for k, v in servers.iteritems() if answer in v]:
        print "\nThe domain is in " + v + ".\n"
```

The script is as follows. Any suggestions other than the original one is welcome.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import dns.resolver
import sys

servers = {
'UK':['127.0.0.1'],
'USA':['127.0.0.2','127.0.0.3','127.0.0.4'],
'AUS':['127.0.1.1','127.0.1.2']
}

website = sys.argv[1]

try:
    nameserver = dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
    nameserver.nameservers = ['198.40.3.6','198.40.3.7']
    answer = nameserver.query(website)[0]

    answer = str(answer)

    if [k for k, v in servers.iteritems() if answer in v]:
        print "\nThe domain is in " + v + ".\n"

except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

It should give the correct 'key' but it is not. It is giving the same output.

Comment: Can you please provide an example for an `answer` value?
In addition, I think what you wanted to print is print `k` (the country of the server).

Comment: Still 2.7? Please use the latest version of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your `if` check and the `print` statement following it are faulty. There's nothing specifically incorrect about how you're finding keys (though you could do it more efficiently), but you're not using that result at all in the rest of your code, so it doesn't really matter.

Try changing your code to this:

```
matched_keys = [k for k, v in servers.iteritems() if answer in v] # same list comp as before
if matched_keys:
    print print "\nThe domain is in " + str(matched_keys) + ".\n" # or maybe use matched_keys[0]?
```

The way I coded it above will print out the list of all keys that have the answer in them, if there are any. If you're sure there can only be one result, you can use `matched_keys[0]`.

Note that if you expect to be doing this sort of check a lot, with the same set of servers, you should probably change your data structure so that you can do a more efficient check. The current one is O(M*N) where `M` is the number of checks you need to do and `M` is the number of values in the dictionary. You could turn that into O(M) by constructing a reversed dictionary:

```
reversed_servers = {}
for k, v in servers.iteritems():
    for address in v:
        reversed_servers.setdefault(address, []).append(k) # or reversed_servers[address] = k
```

You only need to do this setup once. Later you can do any number of efficent lookups with just `reversed_servers[answer]`, with no loop needed.

Note that the code above sets up a dictionary containing lists of all matching keys, if there can be only one for each address (because the values are unique), then you can use the alternative version in the comment, which will map from address to key directly (without a list).

Comment: Thanks. It gives exactly what I was looking for. Marking this as an answer. Yes, I expect only one answer and hence used `str(matched_keys[0])`. However, I have another problem related to nameservers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = [k for k in servers.keys() if answer in servers[k]]
if result:
    print "\nThe domain is in " + str(servers[result[0]]) + ".\n"
```

To print the corresponding key, you can use `result[0]`.

Comment: just replaced and ran. It gave me "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects"

Comment: Ah yes, that's because `servers[result[0]]` will be a list. You may wrap that with `str()` to get it to print the value. Will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: It printed the list of values. I have marked another as answer which prints as expected. Thank you so much for you time.